# Quasar QSelect popup and input text persistent on click

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to set up a QSelect driven by user input in order to achieve an "autocomplete" behavior. There are a few examples on the official documentation and they make use of the @filter callback.

I have currently two problems:

1. Whenever I click outside of the input field the input text is lost and the popup disappears.
2. If I click on the input the current text remains, but the pop is hidden until I click on it again.

For the latter issue, one workaround is to force the popup to show upon click:

```
<q-select
  ref="input"
  ...
  @click.native.prevent="onClick"
>
...
onClick(){
  if( this.searchFilter.length > 0){
    this.$refs.input.showPopup()
  }
}
```

However, the inconvenience is that the popup still shortly disappears for a short while before showing again. I've also tried using `@click.native.stop` instead of `@click.native.prevent` to no avail.

As for issue number 1 I haven't even found a workaround yet.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606626/prevent-click-propagation-outside-of-quasar-q-select) is a related issue, though the popup disappearing was a wanted behavior in his case.

I set up a basic [Pen](https://codepen.io/edwillys/pen/bGwraYE?editors=1010) to illustrate the issue. Try clicking on the input or outside the input at the same height.

Comment: Interesting issue. I also came up with some hacky solution: listen for event @popup-show and if it's true and this.searchFilter.length > 0 then call showPopup()

Comment: Could you provide a codepen for that problem?

Comment: @DavidGo: Did you mean listening to popup-hide and call showPopup() to force its persistency? I tried it too and the flickering effect is still there. Pen example is added to the post above.

Comment: hm, in the codepen example I type "a" and click outside the input and it doesn't hide popup, even If I remove onClick method

Comment: but if my click is on the level with input it dissappears

Comment: ah, that's because we don't have content for the whole screen, I fixed that here, now we can try to fix your issue:) https://codepen.io/DavidGolodetsky/pen/OJRjQjm

Comment: True. I updated on my Pen too. Now it doesn't matter where you click outside of the input, the popup always hides. Latest I check, your pen was missing the callback to onClick: `@click.native.prevent="onClick" `

Comment: hm, it does look to me that you would need to create your own q-input and q-menu component for that. It looks like the type of functionality that should be provided by Quasar, so maybe you can create a feature request.

Comment: for q-menu you have `persistent` prop. Would be great to have that for select dropdown as well https://quasar.dev/vue-components/menu#Persistent

Comment: ah, there is another component for that from Quasar: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/button-dropdown
It also works with q-menu and does have `persistent` prop. Tell me if it works for you so I could create an answer

Comment: I'm aware of the `persistent` prop for QMenu. However, this wouldn't be an answer as my post is related to QSelect. If there is really no way, I'll create a feature request on Quasar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to use `@click.capture.native` and then conditionally stop the propagation inside the callback function via `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` See it working [here](https://codepen.io/edwillys/pen/bGwraYE?editors=1010)

Comment: it doesn't work properly if I write something and click outside on q-select it shows a blank value.